# Delete an element in a hash without deleting the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I want to delete an element from a hash in Rails.  The `delete` method looks promising, and works well with one unintended consequence... it deletes the model.

```
# Get all users.
@search = User.all

# Unset yourself. Your ID is stored in current_user.id
@users.delete(current_user.id)
```

The resulting @users hash does in fact have your own ID removed... but it also deletes the model. What is the correct way to simply unset that key in Ruby / Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you  describe isn't accurate on *many* counts. First, `User.all` returns an array, not a hash, so assuming you're using ActiveRecord here, the premise of your question is flawed.

Secondly, deleting an item from an array using [`Array#delete`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-delete) will definitely not invoke `delete` on the item itself.  That just isn't true. It wouldn't do so for a hash either.

Thirdly, it *also* won't delete the item from the array at all, unless its index happens to match the index of the item in the array, which isn't very likely. You're wildly misinterpreting you experiment.

You don't delete things from an array by passing some field belonging to the object (like ID) to `Array#delete`. You need to pass the array index. You would need to figure out the index of the record matching your current user, and pass *that* into `delete`.

However, if you want to remove an object from array by one of its properties, using `reject` is much better:

```
@users.reject! { |u| u.id == current_user.id }
```

Comment: Thanks @meagar! I thought my @users hash was keyed on the id of the model

Comment: It's not a hash, it's an array. They're radically different things.

Comment: hey @meagar, it might be confusing if you say that `User.all` returns an array since for Rails 4, it returns a relation.